# a moveit pr2 tutorial terminates with a mutex_lock error

Tags: c++, moveit, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run a moveit pr2 tutorial like so:

```
roslaunch pr2_moveit_tutorials move_group_interface_tutorial.launch
```

and it runs through different motions fine but at the end it shows an error and then just hangs. Is this an expected behaviour. What should I do to get rid of this error message and have the program finish cleanly? The error message looks like this:

```
move_group_interface_tutorial: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:110: void boost::recursive_mutex::lock(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_lock(&m)' failed.
[move_group_interface_tutorial-7] process has died [pid 13649, exit code -6, cmd /home/andrey/misc/ros/devel/lib/pr2_moveit_tutorials/move_group_interface_tutorial __name:=move_group_interface_tutorial __log:=/home/andrey/.ros/log/dbebe4c8-97ad-11e4-ba0e-90b11c98a3ed/move_group_interface_tutorial-7.log].
log file: /home/andrey/.ros/log/dbebe4c8-97ad-11e4-ba0e-90b11c98a3ed/move_group_interface_tutorial-7*.log
```

moveit_pr2 and the necessary pr2 modules are compiled and installed with catkin_make from source (indigo).

I also had a look at master.log and it shows the following error (not sure if it's relevant):

```
[rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2015-01-09 14:49:10,269: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/threadpool.py", line 218, in run
result = cmd(*args)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 208, in publisher_update_task
xmlrpcapi(api).publisherUpdate('/master', topic, pub_uris)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
return self.parse_response(response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
return u.close()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault -1: 'publisherUpdate: unknown method name'>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200639/a-moveit-pr2-tutorial-terminates-with-a-mutex_lock-error/) by [andsok75](https://answers.ros.org/users/21315/andsok75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on 2018-01-08**:
same problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure moveit_pr2 and the pr2 modules are intended to work on Indigo at the moment. Do you mind filing a bug report on the moveit_pr2 github located here https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/issues. I'm unsure if this is a MoveIt bug or a PR2 specific bug at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0